# How do I apply the assembly:ThemeInfo attribute with an auto-generated AssemblyInfo?

Tags: c#, wpf, assemblyinfo, roslyn-project-system

After the migration to the new VS 2017 project system, the AssemblyInfo.cs file is now auto-generated by default. How can I add the `assembly:ThemeInfo[]` attribute to my project that is required by WPF to find the default `Themes\generic.xaml`file without disabling the auto-generation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually matter where the attribute is placed, it is not required to be in a file named `AssemblyInfo.cs`. Assembly-level attributes can be placed anywhere, it doesn't even need to be a class. I ultimately put them in a file named `AssemblyAttributes.cs` in the project in case there will be other attributes that need to be added.